# Can't add schema for postgres inside docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to build a debian image in Docker that contains nginx, postgresql and php-fpm. I've managed to get nginx and php-fpm working. Postgres is also working but I can't add the schema to the database I have created.

The code from Dockerfile relating to postgres (got it from docker website) is the following:

```
# Add database
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-9.4 postgresql-client-9.4 postgresql-contrib-9.4
# Run the rest of the commands as the ``postgres`` user created by the ``postgres-9.4`` package when it was ``apt-get installed``
USER postgres

# Create a PostgreSQL role named ``use_name`` with ``user_password`` as the password and
# then create a database `database_name` owned by the ``use_name`` role.
# Note: here we use ``&&\`` to run commands one after the other - the ``\``
#       allows the RUN command to span multiple lines.
RUN    /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER user_name WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'user_password';" &&\
    createdb -O user_name database_name

# Adjust PostgreSQL configuration so that remote connections to the
# database are possible. 
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf

# And add ``listen_addresses`` to ``/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf``
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf

# Reload postgres configuration
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql stop && /etc/init.d/postgresql start

# Add database schema
COPY ./postgresql/database_name.sql /tmp/database_name.sql
RUN psql -U use_name -d database_name -a -f /tmp/database_name.sql
```

The error I get is

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Is there another way to do this that I have not seen? Do I need to do something more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't connect to the server is because it isn't running. Each line in a Dockerfile is processed in a new container, so any old processes are no longer running, but changes to the filesystem will persist (provided they weren't made to a volume).

You could start the database in the same `RUN` instruction as the psql command, but normally this sort of thing would be done in an `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` script that runs when the container is started.

By the far the best plan is to do as @h3nrik suggests and use the official `postgres` image. Even if you don't want to do this, it's worth looking at the Dockerfile and scripts (e.g https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/tree/master/9.5) used to build the official image to understand how they tackled the same problems.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I've tried linking containers but I haven't been able to make it work, do you know a good tutorial to follow? I did all the steps but I can't make it work :(

Comment: Yep I did, and after linking a couple of containers nothing worked... I gues I need to keep trying

Comment: If there is something specific that isn't working like you think it should, open a new question.

Comment: I'm trying to build a LEMP but with postgres instead of mysql and I tried using exsiting containers and building them myself using a debian based container. When I completed the process I was not being able to access the nginx server through the browser...

Also I find it hard to use some of the containers, I guess I just need to try it more

Answer (score 2):

I would not put the nginx and postgres installations in one single docker container. I would create a separate postgres container and [link](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/) to it from the nginx/php-fpm container.

The postgres container I would base on the [official one](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/). There it is also described how you can add your custom schema to the postgres installation (please have a look at the comment of *justfalter*, there).

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to make it work by linking containers but I haven't been able to make it work